# how to cross validate pca in sklearn pipeline without overfitting?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, cross-validation, feature-selection

My input is time series data. I want to decompose the dataset with PCA (I dont want to do PCA on the entire dataset first because that would be overfitting) and then use feature selection on each component (fitted on a KNN Regressor model).

This is my code so far:

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=10)
pca = PCA(n_components=.5,svd_solver='full').fit_transform()
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(estimator=knn,n_features_to_select='auto',tol=.001,scoring=custom_scorer,n_jobs=-1)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("pca", pca), ("sfs", sfs), ("knn", knn)])
cv_score = cross_val_score(estimator=pipe,X=X,y=y,scoring=custom_scorer,cv=tscv,verbose=10)
print(np.average(cv_score),' +/- ',np.std(cv_score))
print(X.columns)
```

The problem is I want to make sure PCA isnt looking over the entire dataset when it calculates which features variance. I also want it to be fit transformed, but it doesnt work. With the following error codes:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' '<bound method PCA.fit_transform of PCA(svd_solver='full')>' (type <class 'method'>) doesn't
```

or

```
TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `pca = PCA(...).fit_transform` nor `pca = PCA(...).fit_transform()` when defining your pipeline.

Instead, you should use `pca = PCA(...)`. The `fit_transform` method is automatically called within the pipeline during the model fitting (in `cross_val_score`).

Comment: How do we know it uses fit vs fit_transform?

Comment: @TomwardMatthias when calling `.fit()` or `.fit_transform()` on a Pipeline instance, `.fit_transform()` is called sequentially on *all intermediate transformers but the last one*  (on which it either `.fit()` or `.fit_transform()` is called depending on the method called on the Pipeline itself; the one in the last step is indeed more generally an *estimator* rather than a *transformer*). Indeed a pipeline is meant to *transform* data sequentially. Eventually, in `cross_val_score` `.fit()` is called on the pipeline, but, as said, `.fit_transform()` is called automatically on 'pca' transformer.

Comment: One more question @amiola, after the code has been ran, how do I find which principal components have been selected by sequential feature selection?

Comment: You can obtain the computed PCs with `pipe[0].components_` (or equivalently `pipe.named_steps["pca"].components_`), and the selected features with `pipe[1].support_` (or equivalently `pipe.named_steps["sfs"].support_`).

Comment: I get ```'SequentialFeatureSelector' object has no attribute 'support_'``` when using ```pipe.named_steps["sfs"].support_```

Comment: The attribute only exists after the fit. In scikit-learn, attributes existing after the fit are named with an underscore at the end `_`.